# Edit table row in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, edit, cfml

I use `cftable` or `cfloop` to output a table of items in ColdFusion. But what is the right way to call the editor page on clicking one of table rows?

Here is the code:

```
<table class="grid">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Urgency</th>
    <th>Severity</th>
</tr>
<cfloop query="GetIssues">
<tr>
    <td><cfoutput>#id#</cfoutput></td>
    <td><cfoutput>#CreatedOn#</cfoutput></td>
    <td><cfoutput>#ShortDesc#</cfoutput></td>
    <td><cfoutput>#Status#</cfoutput></td>
    <td><cfoutput>#Urgency#</cfoutput></td>
    <td><cfoutput>#Severity#</cfoutput></td>
</tr>
</cfloop>
</table>
```

I could use `a href` to make GET request to editor page, but is it the right/safe way?

Comment: First....do not use cftable. Second...can we see some code?

Comment: @Scott Stroz: Updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly create a link to the editor page and pass the ID, however, if your IDs are numeric, it will be easy for nefarious users to guess the ID of another item. To mitigate this issue, I tend to use UUIDs for my IDs. It is extremely difficult to guess at the ID of another element.

Also, it is better to wrap the cfloop in a cfoutput, rather than wrapping each td - and you should scope your variable names.

For example:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop query="GetIssues">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="edit.cfm?id=#GetIssues.id#">#GetIssues.id#</a></td>
        <td>#GetIssues.CreatedOn#></td>
        <td>#GetIssues.ShortDesc#</td>
        <td>#GetIssues.Status#</cfoutput></td>
        <td>#GetIssues.Urgency#</cfoutput></td>
        <td>#GetIssues.Severity#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You can achieve the same result with less code by using cfoutput with a query attribute.  Also, if you ever intend to make the key field part of a form field name, the hyphens in the uuid may cause a problem.  I have vague recollections of something like that happening to me.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: could you write an example?

Comment: @DanBracuk Using cfoutput with query attribute only saves 2 lines of code :D. Doing it the way I showed will also make it easier to loop over other queries, if need be, inside the main loop. I have used UIDS values inside form field names and IDs and never had an issue with it